# how to put a new intent in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a Tabs menu in android:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.5"
    />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:drawablePadding="0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="0dip"
                android:paddingRight="0dip"
                android:paddingStart="0dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

I want to start a new intent and put it in the FrameLayout (when a the correspondent tab is clicked):

I tried like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, tab1.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but the result is a new activity that hides the tab menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a fragment for this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

c.f. [Android Developers API Guides on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

Comment: So you'd have different Fragments for tab 1, 2, ... and just add them to the layout with `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.tabcontent, fragment)` or replace the existing content with `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tabcontent, fragment)`